# Are regular expressions $LR(k)$?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars, parsers, regular-expressions

If I have a Type 3 Grammar, it can be represented on a pushdown automaton (without doing any operation on the stack) so I can represent regular expressions by using context free languages. But can I know if a type 3 grammar is $LR(1)$, $LL(1)$, $SLR(1)$, etc. without constructing any parse tables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All regular languages have LL(1) grammars.  To obtain such a grammar, take any DFA for the regular language (perhaps by doing the subset construction on the NFA obtained from the regular expression), then convert it to a right-recursive regular grammar.  This grammar is then LL(1), because any pair of productions for the same nonterminal either start with different symbols, or one produces ε and has $ as a lookahead token.  Consequently, all regular languages are also LR(1), since any LL(1) grammar is LR(1).  Additionally, using [an important result from this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321972), you can show that any LR(1) language has an SLR(1) grammar, meaning that any regular language has an SLR(1) grammar.

However, the regular languages are *not* all LR(0).  The LR(0) languages have very specific properties - in particular, they must be prefix-free.  Thus the regular language {a, aa} is not LR(0), though it's clearly regular (regex a|(aa)).  However, the LR(0) languages are not properly contained within the regular languages; this grammar for { 0<sup>n</sup>21<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ 1 } is LR(0), but the language is not regular:

```
S -> E
E -> 0E1 | 2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The fact that right-regular grammars accept exactly the set of regular languages is usually done in class (or even the exercises), so the answer is that much more immediate.

Answer (score 2):

(Plain old) regular expression *syntax* (you said "representation") is LR(0).  You don't need any lookahead to parse a string representing a regex.  You can easily decide this by running a parser generator on a grammar for regexes :-}   You can also easily code a simple recursive descent (LL(0)) parser for regexps; anything which is LL(0) is LR(0).

I don't know if the syntax of more complicated so-called "regexps" such as Perl's are like this; but Perl's regexps are strictly more powerful than regexps so they are not plain old regexps.

To determine if a grammar has some property, you have to run some kind of predicate.
To determine if it is (S)LR(k), you have to run a predicate that can check for that property. In effect, any such predicate must in effect build the parse tables, because of the way they are defined.

Comment: Perl regular expressions works on NFA

Comment: The question wasn't about how Perl regexps worked.  It was about whether (Perl?) regexps were parsable by certain technologies.  I can believe Perl regexps use a NFA to do their matching, along with some other context-sensitive data capture, but I don't see the relevance to the question.

Comment: I would have thought that perl's regex do need lookahead, just looking at the simple feature of 'greedy' vs. 'non greedy' tokens.

Comment: -1 The regular expressions are **not** LR(0).  LR(0) languages must be prefix-free, but the regular expression `a|(aa)` describes a language that is not prefix-free.  Additionally, LR(0) languages cannot handle grammars with epsilon productions, so the regular language { epsilon, a } is not LR(0).  However, the regular languages *are* LL(1) because you can write them as regular grammars, and thus they are all LR(1).  Since any LR(1) language has an SLR(1) grammar, this means all regular languages are SLR(1).

Comment: Concerning LL(0), it's the other way around: LL(0) languages are a proper subset of regular languages. Note that LL(0) means that you don't use lookahead for deciding between different derivations - which basically means there are no decisions and the language consists of a single word. LR(0), in contrast, is a useful class - again you don't use lookahead to decide (here for reductions), but there still is some diversity due to the fact that shifting can distinguish between different productions.

Comment: I read his question as, 'Is the *syntax* of a regular expression LR(0)', not "can regular expressions handle LL(0) languages".

Comment: @IraBaxter- The syntax of regular expressions is not LR(0) either because the regular expressions aren't prefix free.  They aren't LL(0) either, because LL(0) languages can only contain a single string (or no strings).

Comment: OK, so I'm missing something.  What's a specific example of regexp that an LR(0) parser can't process? I'm imagining the usual expression grammar (alternation, sequence, postfix kleene star, parentheses).

Comment: Try the regular language { a, aa }.  No LR(0) grammar exists for this language; you'll always get a shift/reduce conflict or reduce/reduce conflict somewhere.

Comment: @IraBaxter- Also note that any *specific* regular expression could be parsed by an LR(0) parser, but no LR(0) grammar exists that generates *all* regular expressions.