# Are all Chomsky-Type3 grammars LL(1)?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Referring to [this Question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/are-regular-expressions-lrk), where an answer is stating that all Type 3 languages are LL(1), I'd like to know if all Type 3 grammars are possibly LL(1).

If not, why is it so? Are there maybe ambiguous grammars in the set of the Type 3 grammars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chomsky hierarchy is primarily a hierarchy of grammars, not of
languages. As stated in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy):

> The Chomsky hierarchy (occasionally referred to as
>     Chomsky-Schützenberger hierarchy) is a containment hierarchy of
>     classes of formal grammars.

Type 3 grammars are characterized by the fact that they have to have
only left linear rules (i.e., productions), or only right linear rules,
plus possibly an empty rule for the initial non-terminal symbol. For
any language, both forms exist.

A rule is left linear iff its right hand side (RHS) is composed of a
terminal symbol, possibly preceded by a single non-terminal.

A rule is right linear iff its right hand side (RHS) is composed of a
terminal symbol, possibly followed by a single non-terminal.

(There are small [variants of these definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar), allowing for a
terminal string of any length, instead of a single terminal)

When the language is not finite, some of the rules are necessarily
recursive. But a left linear rules that is recursive is necessarily
left recursive. Hence the grammar is not LL(1).

Hence some type 3 grammars, even with the strict definition above, are
not LL(1).

Comment: It is customary to consider only the right-linear grammars as type-3, because of the "natural order" of derivations. Even then the grammars are not always LL(1), because of nondeterminism.

Comment: This answer can be completed further: 1) not all type-3 grammars are LL(1) 2) all type-3 languages are LL(1), as they can all be described by deterministic right linear grammars, which are LL(1).

Comment: @HendrikJan I trusted Wikipedia, but you are correct. I checked the
original Chomsky papers, and the hierarchy is apparently defined in
the 1959 paper, not the 56 paper as asserted by Wikipedia. And indeed,
he considers only right-linear grammars, unlike most authors citing
him. Well, I guess it is fairer to consider both as we do not all
write from left to right :-). This said, I quite agree that
non-determinism is another issue. Actually, given an LL(1) grammar,
there are usually plenty of ways to make it non-LL(1) without changing
the language.

Comment: @babou (1) In my intuition the type-3 grammar should work the same direction as the LL(1) one, to get a natural match. In that case nondeterminsism seems the reason that spoils LL(1). (2) Thanks for your investigations, great you checked Chomsky. Personally, I no longer follow wikipedia here: although initially defined as a grammar hierarchy, it now seems more proper to see it as a language hierarchy with both grammars and machines to underline it is such a natural concept.

Comment: @HendrikJan Your argument is a good one regarding right linear and
LL(1) is a good one. Regarding hierarchies, the language view supports
my answer. Still, I think all views have value. What often matter is
not just language as set of sring, but also associating some structure
with the strings. Else why work on such things as ambiguity? Outside
pure formal language theory, languages matter as syntactic backbone of
other structures. It is fair to account for people concerned by that,
as Chomsky was. I have seen people downvoted, apparently for
considering that syntactic structure matters.

Comment: @HendrikJan Not everywhere. We had both left- and right-regular grammars.

Comment: @Raphael Brrr. I don't fancy "regular grammars". Regular is the languages, right-linear the grammars, finite state the automata. That is how I was raised...

Comment: @HendrikJan: There are so many "regular" things in mathematics and TCS, I guess it's not harmful to say "regular grammar = left- or right-linear grammar" as a shorthand. (Using left-regular is probably bad, whoops.)